# Use enum in Entity Framework Table :what for?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, enums

Good day,

I have been learning some Entity Framework and I came to this code

```
public   class Test
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public testEnum testEnum { get; set; }

}
public enum testEnum {
    numero1=1,
    numero2=2
}
```

Then I run add-migration xxxxx  and update-database, the problem is that when I go to SQL server, I can not see the enum anywhere.
My questions are: 
1.What happened with the enum and how can I see it in SQL server?
2. When do I use enum instead of a table like the following:

```
public class EnumReplace{ public int Id { get; set; }
 public int value{ get; set; }
}
```

thank you.

Comment: The enum is defined in your app. It does not (and will not) need to be repeated in your database. If you have a class with a property `public testEnum MyProperty { get; set; }` the value of the enum will be stored in database table associated with that class

Comment: To change an enum (i.e. add another value) you will need to recompile your code. To add another value as you show in your `EnumReplace` class, just needs a new entry in the database. So if the values are unlikely to change, for example an order status might be `New`, `Processed` and `Dispatched` and unlikely to ever change, then stick with an enum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
1.What happened with the enum and how can I see it in SQL server?
```

The enum gets stored in the database table as an integer. You wouldn't be able to see the enumeration in the database. EF takes the responsibility of casting the underlying type to the enumeration defined while retrieving the values from the database.

In Entity Framework, an enumeration can have the following underlying types: Byte, Int16, Int32, Int64 , or SByte.
Read more about enum support in EF code first [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh859576(v=vs.113).aspx)

```
2. When do I use enum instead of a table like the following:
```

When we have a predefined set of values allowed for a property/field, we usually use enumeration. For e.g.

```
enum Days 
{ 
 Sat, 
 Sun, 
 Mon, 
 Tue, 
 Wed, 
 Thu, 
 Fri
};
```

You could also use Flagged Enums, Read more about enum [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/enum).

Answer (score 0):

you have to have the enum in your class. something like this:

```
 public testEnum MyProperty{ get; set; }
```

so basically you can't have enum as a table. you can have enum as a type of one of your properties in a table.